# Button redirects to wrong page if clicked [PHP]

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a script to write data from an HTML form into a database. Now I also want to edit an entry, so it's possible to search for something and by clicking an image it should be possible to edit the entry.

```
function writeAll($data, $pk) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        if(strcasecmp($key, "plz") == 0) {
            $key = "PLZ";
        } else if(strcasecmp($key, "tel_handy") == 0) {
            $key = "mobiltelefon";
        } else if(strcasecmp($key, "tel_festnetz") == 0) {
            $key = "festnetztelefon";
        }

        echo '
            <td>'.
                $value.'
            </td>
        ';
    }
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id='.$pk.'"><input type="image" src="button_edit.png" /></a></td></tr>';
}
```

That's the line of code which creates the button beside each entry, with the entry id connected to it.

But if I click the button/image, I always get to the page

```
localhost/php/index.html?x=20&y=101
```

(index.html is the form page.)
If more code is needed, let me know.

Why do I get to this page ?

**EDIT:** Added the whole loop code.

Comment: We need to see the whole loop that creates the buttons, and the db call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change :

```
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id='.$pk.'"><input type="image" src="button_edit.png" /></a></td></tr>';
```

to :

```
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id='.$pk.'"><img src="button_edit.png" /></a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
I changed my code and it works, thanks a lot